# Baggage Allowance on Precision Air

Tags: air-travel, luggage, tanzania, kenya

The listed baggage allowance on Precision Air is 23kg for economy class between Kenya and Tanzania. I'd like to know if that means I can have two pieces of luggage with a combined weight of 23kg, or if it's restricted to one piece.

Answer (score 1):

The [website](https://www.precisionairtz.com/index.php?id=36) would seem to imply it's one bag with a maximum weight of 23 kg. You can apparently take two bags but you would then be charged $200 extra.